# How to rewrite part of an url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Suppose I've urls

```
http://www.example.com/se/products/details/23
http://www.example.com/se/company/about
http://www.example.com/se/customers/europe/john-doe
etc.
```

I want them to `rewrite` to

```
http://www.example.com/en/products/details/23
http://www.example.com/en/company/about
http://www.example.com/en/customers/europe/john-doe
etc
```

That means no matter what language comes they're rewrited to `en`, they see their respective language in address bar, but page is being server from 'en'

My rules look like this

```
# Pass through the original path as a query parameter, and retain the existing parameters.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule .* framework/main.php?url=%1 [QSA]

    RewriteRule ^se/(.+?)\/?$ /en/$1 [L]
```

The project is based on `SilverStripe` framework.

And this didn't work, shows 404 page not found error

How can we do this?

Comment: "this didn't work". What happens? Can you show us rewrite log?

Comment: @undone, it shows 404 page not found error

Comment: What about rewrite log? can you put the log here?

Comment: Do you have other rules in your .htaccess? Also what is location of your .htaccess?

Comment: @undone rewrite log file is empty, no any issue there.

Comment: @anubhava, htaccess is in the root of my project folder, please check my update for the other rules in htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reorder your rules and have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^se(/.*)?$ en$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ framework/main.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this,

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^se/(.+?)\/?$ /en/$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^se/(.*) en/$1 [L]
```

Comment: This didn't work, first one give 500 error and second leads you to 404 error.

Comment: two things, i am assuming you are applying these rule in root and second you have to handle the rewrite of en/text/text with some other internal rewrite to original url ex `page.php?lang?=en&detail=23` please check or provide original url.

Comment: Actually the project is based on `SilverStripe` framework, so there is no original url as you have specified. Silverstripe has its own way of routing the urls.